# t.test from summary statistics in R?

Tags: r

In R, prop.test can take a table of summary statistics (the cell counts from a cross tabulation) instead of all the data (see parameter x [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/prop.test.html)):

> x - a vector of counts of successes, a one-dimensional table with two entries, **or a two-dimensional table (or matrix) with 2 columns, giving the counts of successes and failures**, respectively.

Is there a way to give [t.test](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/t.test.html) (or some equivalent function) the summary statistics of mean, standard deviation, and group size for the two groups and have it perform the appropriate calculations?

Comment: Why has this question been downvoted? I'm interested in the answer.

Comment: Like what? If you have the means/variances of the groups, just calculate the statistic using the appropriate formula. And `t.test` takes the argument `x` as data just like `prop.test`. A table with successes and failures is NOT a summary statistic.

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning behind your question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I assume that you have means, standard deviations, and sample sizes for each group.  I don't know if this is already written somewhere, but it would be easy to write by implementing the basic rules for computing the pooled variance etc.; you will need `pt` to compute the p-value. `stats:::t.test.default` has all the necessary machinery, but is complicated because it handles lots of different cases and does lots of input-checking.

Comment: @Glen_b If you submit that as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Moved and expanded so it's more like an actual answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's already at least one package at CRAN which does the summary statistic version of the t-test, see the function `tsum.test` in package [BSDA](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BSDA/index.html).

[This question on stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30394/how-to-perform-two-sample-t-tests-in-r-by-inputting-sample-statistics-rather-tha) includes a couple of sets of R code that should also suffice.

Notes:

The answers there don't seem to take advantage of the `htest` class. I probably would have for consistency, though it's not such a big issue.

What I'd actually *like* to see is `t.test` able to take a mix (both samples with observations or both with summaries, or *one of each*, which I don't think `tsum.test` does either), *and* I'd like to see t.test properly handle the case of one sample with only a single observation (with `var.equal=TRUE` only, naturally); as it stands all these additions are simple to do and not so infrequently required, it surprises me that the small number of additional lines are not simply inserted.

(Funny that that question was migrated the other direction from yours, I think they're pretty similar; in borderline cases, I guess there's going to be some questions that are migrated away that the people at the other end of the migration think should stay where they were. It may be that my question to you, and your answer, was actually what triggered the move in this case.)

Comment: I ended up using the code from stats.stackexchange: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30450/2849.